# SSIS Webservice Task

Tags: web-services, ssis

If webservice returns No value(return type is Array of Event) am getting an error   SSIS Package calling websrvice task   and output assigning to xmlfile.If the value is there ,No error,only when no value,then package fails. how to handle webservice task when it fails

Comment: developing SSIS package consuming Local Webservice

Comment: Do you want it to continue on without failing?  What do you want it to do?

Comment: want to know why it is failing,web service return type is Array[]type(complex datatype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created  the dll to consume the webservice and converted the array[] complex type into flat datatable to return. Now  even if the return data is null no error because the flat table,previously we have the arra[] complex type with return null values breaks.